# PHP PDO and oracle db "could not find driver"

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

I already enabled the `extension=php_pdo_oci.dll` in php and apache I also restarted the wampserver but still no still having this error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'`

luck I don't know what is missing here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check the list of adapters `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()`

Comment: it only print mysql\nsqlite\nsqlsrv\n .. where to download the driver ?

Comment: it may help you [ https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_OCI ]

Comment: how to install it after download ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the PDO Oracle driver adapter:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php

Comment: I don't understand this `Using $ORACLE_HOME`

Comment: how to configure ` $ORACLE_HOME` ?

Comment: Neither do I. I suggest you take a look at [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_HOME).

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables in the config file:

On Ubuntu in /etc/apache2/envvars:

```
export CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.CP1252
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
export NLS_LANG AMERICAN
```

or in the vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName oracleapp.example.org
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_example.org.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_example.org.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_example.org.chain
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  SetEnv ORACLE_HOME /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
  SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
  SetEnv NLS_LANG AMERICAN
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oracleapp.example.org-ssl-error_log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oracleapp.example.org-ssl-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Pro tip: Don't set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client